# Why am I getting Empty Response from this Request iOS JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, rest

**Objective C Codes**

```
@try {
        NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://yyy.com/api/Customer/"];
        NSDictionary *myDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.firstNameTextField.text, CustFirstName,
                               self.lastNameTextField.text, CustLastName,
                               nil];

        NSError *error;

        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

        if (!jsonData) {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        } else {

            // Get our Access Token back
            NSString *savedToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                    stringForKey:@"savedToken"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:postURL];
            [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
            [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
            [request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
            [request setValue:savedToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
            [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

            //NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSLog(@"Saving Success!");
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"edit_add_customer" sender:self];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Saving Fail!");
                [self alertStatus:@"Please try again" :@"Saving Fail" :0];
            }


        }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
    [self alertStatus:@"Error Retrieving Customer Data." :@"Error!" :0];
}
```

Anyway my JSON string is correct, as I place in my Rest Client. It was able to save.
I try to log my response StatusCode and it is showing as '0'. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you miss the connection: NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                         delegate:self]; ?

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to get statusCode before you do actual request

```
  NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
  NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

you have to check the statusCode after the request

```
  NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
```

Comment: Hi sorry to get back late. Yes I guess your code is making it work but I am now receiving a response of 500 instead of an empty response. Still trying to think what is wrong with my codes as Rest Client works.

Comment: HTTP Error 500 "Internal Server Error". The server is not able to do something. Try to "Reset Content and Settings" in your emulator. Probably you will get the same then as on your phone.

Comment: Thanks you are great. Wow that works. Thats weird, now I could POST data successfully. Why is it so?

Comment: Ask your customer to check the logs on the server side. maybe you need to change some setValues in the request or they have some exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. Will notify them. :)